# Customizing a peripheral in Renode - IMachine could not be found

Tags: c#, renode

I'm trying to modify a SPI peripheral ([this one](https://github.com/renode/renode-infrastructure/blob/master/src/Emulator/Peripherals/Peripherals/SPI/DesignWare_SPI.cs)) and getting this error:

```
Errors during compilation or loading:
There were compilation errors:
renode/modified.cs(21,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IMachine'
could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

The only thing I did in `modified.cs` was to change the file name and class name. Then, in my .resc file I added `include $ORIGIN/renode/modified.cs`. In the .repl file, I changed the name of the device to match the new class name.

I looked at the `modified.cs`, and it does have `using Antmicro.Renode.Core;`, so I don't understand why it can't find `IMachine`.

I'm running Renode version 1.14.0.29506 (81da46c1-202308081623) on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Renode has changed since the last release, and I should have started with an older version of the Infrastructure code. `IMachine` used to be called `Machine`.